# Why does altering a property of a child component affects the parent?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

My application consists of a parent application which has components. My intent was to isolate the component so that the only communication between the parent (the app) and the child (the component) is done via

- props (parent → child)
- and emitted events (child → parent).

I have, however, the problem of an unexpected reactivity: when I change properties in the child component, they also get immediately updated in the parent.

**My overall question is: are props copies of the parent data, or are they pointers?**

Specifically, I send to my child component data defined in the app:

```
<current-incident
  @updated-incident="updateAllincidentsFromIncidentForm"
  :currentIncident="currentIncident"
/>
```

`currentIncident` is defined in the app `data()`:

```
data() {
   return {
      currentIncident: {
         id: null
      },
      allIncidents: {},
   }
},
```

From the component's perspective, what is received as a `prop` is an Object (`props: ['currentIncident']`), which is then assigned to an internal one defined in its `data()` in the `mount()` of the component (`this.incident = this.currentIncident`).

`this.incident` is then modified in the component and eventually sent back up with an `this.$emit()`.

The problem is that the content of the parent's `currentIncident` is modified on the fly when I modify `incident` in the component. **No `$emit()` has happended yet**.

This leads me to think that passing a `prop` via `:currentIncident="currentIncident"` binds bi-directionally `currentIncident`, which in my understanding was exactly why props and emits were created (to break this bidirectional binding)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow):

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component **will** affect parent state.

The solution was to deep clone the prop value (I used [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep)) into a new variable (and then `$emit` it as mentioned in the question)